Composition series of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ as an $A$-module over itself
Let $A = M_2(\mathbb{R})$ and consider $A$ as the regular $A$-module. Show that $A$ has infinitely many composition series.
The submodules of $A$ as the regular $A$-module are the left ideals of $A$, which in this case are isomorphic to $I = \{ ((a,0),(b,0)) | a, b \in \mathbb{R} \}$. Therefore, a composition series of $A$ is of the form ${0} \subset I \subset A$. Now, by multiplying $I$ by the change of basis, I can find infinitely many left ideals of $A$ (since we are over $\mathbb{R}$), and thus infinite composition series. Is it ok?
